# What does "Gig gamification" and "divide" means in this sentence

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

today I received an email with topic like this: 
**Gig gamification, a broader digital divide** + the fast track to transformation.
Microsoft finds a broader digital divide
Microsoft recently released the results of an analysis of US high-speed internet usage, finding that the Federal Communications Commission has grossly understated the number of Americans who lack access to broadband service.

I am not sure what exactly meaning do they mean in this context

Comment: Have you looked up the definitions of "gig", "gamification", and "digital divide"? The meaning of "digital divide" in this context is even included in your excerpt: "the number of Americans who lack access to broadband service" (as compared to those who do not lack access).

Comment: divide is separate

Comment: and gig gamification someone who is playing games ?

Comment: Did you actually look up those phrases, or are you just guessing from your prior knowledge?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A **[gig](http://www.portfoliocreative.com/blog/2017/1/18/job-vs-gig-whats-the-difference-and-why-it-matters)** is a short-term job.

**[Gamefication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamification)** is "the application of game-design elements and game principles in non-game contexts".

The **[digital divide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_divide)** is inequality in access to digital technology.